# Question vanished?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I answered a question...

Remembering... "Using Illustrator open a JPG or PNG and Save as a JPG or PNG" from [this user](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/94570/harper-reinstate-monica).

I answered the question this afternoon.

Now it's gone! It doesn't appear under the user's profile nor as an answer under mine.

I know the user *shouldn't* have been able to remove the question since I provided an answer and the rep amount at this stack wasn't sufficient enough.

**So how'd this question vanish?**

More curious than anything else `:)`

My only speculation is that the user is a Stack Employee therefore having delete powers across all stacks, possibly. I did see the question garnered a down vote from someone, so perhaps that instigated the deletion.

Or perhaps they asked a mod in chat to remove it??

Again.. just really **curious**, that's all.

Comment: Ive seen this happen too. Curious as well.

Comment: I'm also *Curious*.

Comment: For anyone else (with 10k+ rep) looking to find a recently deleted question, you can check the deletion log [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days). Those tools are pretty well hidden, I'm sure a lot of 10k+ users probably don't know they exist :)

Comment: Thanks @JohnB I knew they existed but heck if iI could find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question you are referring to is probably [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133203/how-do-i-work-with-an-image-in-illustrator-and-save-it-back-as-an-image). The error page gives the reason you can no longer see the question: "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

An OP can self-delete a question at any time, *unless* there is more than one answer or an answer has an upvote. Since yours was the only answer, and it was not upvoted, the OP could self-delete.

**EDIT**: Mods have undeleted this question, since it is not fair to Scott that they cannot be rewarded for their answer.

Comment: Ahh thanks Pie! It was the "has an up vote" I was missing. I thought a question merely having an answer, any answer, prevented deletion - which is why I was mystified. Thanks for looking at it --  by the way.. I was fine with it being removed, and was only curious since I thought it *couldn't* be removed by the author. The *last* thing I worry about are votes up or down. `:)`.

Comment: I understand that you don't care about rep points (anymore), but it's the _principle_ of the thing. Point is that a user should be able to be rewarded for their time and effort.